# Gridview with fixed number of items inside ViewPager

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager

I'm new for development in android. I want to display items in Gridview in many pages. 
 For example, my gridview has 50 items and i want to display 10 items per page. When i swipe to next page it will display next 10 items. Any idea how to do that ?

```
page 1                                   page 2                                   page 10
  |  <grid item1>   <grid item2>   |     |  <grid item11>   <grid item12>   |      
  |  <grid item3>   <grid item4>   |next>|  <grid item13>   <grid item14>   |next> ...
  |   .....           .....        |     |   .....           .....          |
```

Comment: Stuck on same situation.